# Inject custom script in angular2 component

Tags: angular, sanitization, javascript-injection

I have api endpoint which returns custom html and script string. I need to tell angular2 it's a safe html and render it into a component template. My code so far:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.template.html',
})
export class AppComponent {

    public htmlToRender: any;

    constructor(
        private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    ) {}

    public ngOnInit(): void {

        const html = `
            <p>Hello</p>
            <p id="a"></p>
            <script>
              document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "World"
              console.log(111);
            </script>
        `;

        this.htmlToRender = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
    }

}
```

In my template I have:

```
'<div [innerHTML]="htmlToRender"></div>'
```

However this does not work. Html and script tag are rendered into template, but script is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

angular2 will compile and render the template into parent html. But it will run any script. So you can not add any `<script>` in your html from server.

Maybe you can try with [ngAfterViewInit](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#afterview) of component. For example, in the `ngAfterViewInit()` function, load your script and evaluate with js function `eval()`.

Comment: This doesn't work in my case because html with <script> tags is returned from server. I tried but did not find a way to use eval function here.